# String split, Java

Tags: java, string

Hi I am hoping for a little direction/help on the following task I am struggling with..

Provide two classes which implement the ConsolePrint interface.

• One is called `SimplePrint` and it will just print the supplied argument directly to the console.
e.g. `simplePrintObject.printInfo(“Heading this is not fancy”);` would output:

> Heading this is not fancy

• One is called `FancyPrint`. It should use `StringTokenizer` or `String.split()` to break up the string.

The first part of the string should be treated as a header and the other parts should be separated by tabs in the output.

e.g. `fancyPrintObject.printInfo(“Heading this is quite fancy”);` would output:

```
*********** Heading **********
    this is quite fancy 

******************************
```

Note: You should aim to have both “starred” rows take up the same width, regardless of the size of the header (for example, you can assume that the maximum length of the header string is 20 and that the first and last rows will output 30 characters – which will be 30 * in the case of the last row.)

Provide a basic class called `ConsolePrintTest` which will test each of the two classes. Make sure that your classes can handle empty strings and null strings.

So far I have written my interface as directed:

```
 public interface ConsolePrint
 {  
    void printInfo(String infoToPrint);
 }
```

And a small program using the `Split.split` method..

```
 public class PrintTester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       String str = new String("\n\n**************Heading************** \n\n\t" +
                               "This Is Quite Fancy\n" +
                               "\n***********************************");
       for (String retval: str.split(" ", 1)) {
          System.out.println(retval);
       }

    }
 }
```

But trying to implement the `ConsolePrint` interface as directed in two classes has me stumped after days of reading and searching!

Comment: Any programmer IRL who designed such an API would be summarily dismissed. There should be *2* parameters: one for the heading and one for the body. At least your split call is correct btw.

Comment: The API was given as is..to be honest I have a little enough knowlege of API's at this point to understand what is acceptable! Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 2):

Read it literally: You have to write two classes.

```
public class SimplePrint implements ConsolePrint {
   public void printInfo(String infoToPrint) {
       // method implementation here
   }
}

public class FancyPrint implements ConsolePrint {
   public void printInfo(String infoToPrint) {
       // method implementation here
   }
}
```

and a test driver:

```
public class ConsolePrintTest  {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ConsolePrint printer = null; 
        // figure out how to instantiate different types.
        for (String arg : args) { 
            printer.printInfo(arg);
        }
    }
}
```